# Socket.IO - how do I close socket with socketID in socket.io 1.3.6?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am developing a application of two-way communication in SocketIO.

I am using the following method to send to a specific user.

```
io.to(socket.id).json.emit('message', message);
```

how do I close socket with socketID in socket.io 1.3.6?

To borrow your wisdom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
io.sockets.connected[socketID].disconnect();
```